# jQuery - update collection is not working. Getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying out `node.js` with `mongodb` by making a simple `CRUD webapp`, but I found myself stuck with the `update function`.

Every time I run the code I always get a [404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmeHe.jpg) error on the console.

Here's my code:

```
function updateRecord(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    //set the _id of the user to be update
    var _id = $(this).parentsUntil('div').parent().attr('rel');

    //create a collection of the updated fields
    var fieldsToBeUpdated = $('#editBox input.updated');

    //create an object of the pairs
    var updatedFields = {};
    $(fieldsToBeUpdated).each(function(){
      var key = $(this).attr('placeholder').replace(" ","").toLowerCase();
      var value = $(this).val();
      updatedFields[key]=value;
    });

    // do the AJAX
    $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: '/users/updaterec/' + _id,
      data: updatedFields
    }).done(function( response ) {

      // Update the table
      populateTable();
      $('#msg').text('Entry Updated');
    });}
```

route:

```
router.put('/updaterec/:id', function(req, res) {
      var db = req.db
      var userToUpdate = req.params.id;
      var doc = { $set: req.body};
      db.collection('userlist').updateById(userToUpdate, doc ,function(err, result) {
        res.send((result === 1) ? { msg: '' } : { msg:'error: ' + err });
      });
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Error you are getting in client side?

Comment: It's on the Server side.

Comment: I think it will be `db.collection('userlist').update` instead of `db.collection('userlist').updateById`

Comment: @Shrabanee thank you. will try

Comment: @Shrabanee it is Error 500 now.

Comment: `userToUpdate` needs to be an object. So it should be `{_id : userToUpdate}`